# Does the collection $\{ \ [n, \infty) \ \mid \ n \in \Bbb N\}$ generate the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\Bbb R$?

Tags: measure-theory

> Does the collection $\mathfrak C = \{ \ [n, \infty) \ \mid \ n \in \Bbb N\}$
>   generate the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\Bbb R$?

I came across this problem in a paper. It seems like the answer is No. But I'm having trouble proving it. The only potential solution I can think of is to present a $\sigma$-algebra that contains $\mathfrak C$ but does not contain certain Borel sets (possibly singleton sets?). But I cannot seem to come up with such a $\sigma$ algebra.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$ consisting of the sets of the form
$$
T\cup B
$$
where $T=\emptyset$ or $T=(-\infty,0]$ and $B$ is a Borel set in $(0,\infty)$.

It is closed under complements, because, if $B$ is a Borel set in $(0,\infty)$,
\begin{gather}
\mathbb{R}\setminus B=(-\infty,0]\cup\bigl((0,\infty)\setminus B\bigr)
\\
\mathbb{R}\setminus\bigl((-\infty,0]\cup B\bigr)=(0,\infty)\setminus B
\end{gather}
Closure under countable unions is easy to prove.

Now $\mathcal{A}$ contains $\mathfrak{C}$, but not the Borel set $(-2,-1)$.

Answer (score 1):

You are right -- it does not generate the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb R$. Consider the set $\left\{\sqrt 2\right\}\in\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$, this is not contained in $\mathfrak C$.

Comment: How do we know that $\{\sqrt 2\}$ is not in the "$\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathfrak C$"?

Comment: I think this is wrong. Any set of form [a,b) is in $\mathcal{C}$, so their countable intersection [a] will be in $\mathcal{C}$ as well.

Comment: @sjm.majewski sure about that? Notice it's written $[n,\infty)\;n\in\mathbb N$ not $n\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: My bad, I thought it's $n \in \mathbb{R}$